# I resigned abruptly within 5 months of joining..will it affect my future employment?

Tags: resignation, india

I am thinking of doing an MBA but i am unsure as to whether it will affect my future employment? How can I minimise the risks of this hurting my future career prospects?

Comment: What is MNC? What is country (yours)? What is question (yours)? What would you like to study? Something "useful" for work or just anything?

Comment: The job appears to be in India, so future employers may want to see the OP's relieving letters from previous jobs.

Comment: The first job after graduation often is not a good fit. You graduated, looked for work a few months and worked somewhere bad for a few months. If you omit this job from your CV, you've only "lost" a few months of experience after graduation. Can you not just start fresh?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered omitting this experience from your CV / resume?  I believe that there is nothing wrong with resigning in your situation: it was not a good fit.

Comment: @gatorback: will you please explain why you believe that? The way you wrote, it is just a simple opinion, which might be false. Think about it: what if I will say: " I believe that it is very wrong to resign in your situation"? Which one would be right, me or you? How can OP choose the right answer?.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can hurt one's career other than their pessimistic mindset.

After completing your MBA, you would still be considered as a fresher.

Mentioning your five months of industry experience can do no harm. You can always mention that pursuing MBA was your main interest and you had a 5-6 months or an year's time before you could join college. And hence you got into this job. Don't reveal everything to your prospective employers.

You need to project even your bad experiences as a learning ones.

P.S. I have just seen your original, non-edited post. So, do you have the relieving letter? If yes, then mention it in your resume. If not, then don't. This applies if you still want to work in India, irrespective of whether you join college for pursuing MBA course or you want to pursue your career in another company.